# rails passes json to javascript file, But javascript shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

So i've got a rails call, It works lovely and passes this into postman (shortened because its huge)

```
SEEvent({"event_id":"ID","date":"Sat 20 Aug 2016, 10:00","suppress_best_available":"","sorted_ticket_types":["000000000001"],"is_resale_eligible":0,"ada_tickets_enabled":0,"suppress_any_price":"","expand_resale_module_ntf":1,"expand_resale_module":"","bba_deep_links_offer_code":
```

For some reason when i try and call it in my javascript file (which looks like this):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/event/'+ event,
  success: function(json) {
    debugger;
```

The error function is shown instead of the success. In the debugger, i have response code 4 and in the response text is all the json i need.

Any help would be amazing

I've tried changing the dataType to jsonp which also didnt work.

Sam

Comment: The data shown seems to be JSONP, assuming the part you truncated ends with a closing bracket. I know you said you tried that, but it's definitely not JSON. Have you tried telling jQuery that the name of the JSONP callback should be `SEEvent`?

Comment: I havent tried this, I'm not sure how i'd do this? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening possibly because this bit - `SEEvent(` is not valid json. The server needs to send valid json only which can be parsed straight away.